# Given a target and missile travelling at constant velocity at what angle must I launch the missile to collide with the target?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

This problem is one which is to have purpose for an enemy missile launcher in a two-dimensional sprite-based video game. I have considered it for some time without an answer.

The purpose is to calculate the angle at which a missile of fixed velocity must be launched in order to collide with a player-controlled object. Assume the player will continue travelling in the same direction they are moving, at the speed they are travelling, at the moment the missile is launched.

I am not sure if that is clear enough information to answer the question so to elaborate:

Assume the player has a craft controlled by an 8-way pad or joystick. This gives them 9 initial directions including stationary. It also gives them two absolute velocities depending on whether the pad is centred or held in one of the 8 directions.

At some other arbitrary point on the 2d screen is a missile launcher. The purpose is to establish at what angle the missile should be launched at some pre-chosen fixed speed to eventually collide with the player. Safe to assume when the player can travel faster than the missile there will be instances when such a collision cannot occur.

Let's provide an example case: At the moment the missile is to be launched the player is holding the joystick in the upper-left position and therefore moving northwest and at a speed of two pixels per frame. Twenty pixels to the right of the player is a missile which can travel at 5 pixels per frame. In this case then the solution would be the angle at which the missile must be launched to eventually collide with the player.

Given that single example what is the general formula to solve the launch angle for a missile travelling at x pixels per frame so it eventually collides with a player travelling in one of the 9 game-pad directions at y pixels per frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target is moving on a straight line given by

$ P(t) = P_0 + t V_1 $

And our missile will be moving along a straight line given by

$ Q(t) = Q_0 + t s u $

where $u = (\cos \theta , \sin \theta) $

The two unknowns here are $t$ and $\phi$.  Intersecting the two lines, we get

$ P(t) = Q(t) = P_0 + t V_1 = Q_0 + t s u $

so

$ t (V_1 - s u) = Q_0 - P_0 $

or

$ V_1 - s u = \dfrac{1}{t} (Q_0 - P_0) $

So we need the vector $V_1 - s u$ to point in the same direction as $Q_0 - P_0$.

Written components wise, we have

$ V_1 - s u = ( V_{1x} - s \cos \theta , V_{1y} - s \sin \theta ) $

Therefore we want,

$  \dfrac{V_{1y} - s \sin \theta}{V_{1x} - s \cos \theta} = \dfrac{ Q_{0y} - P_{0y} } { Q_{0x} - P_{0x} } $

Cross multiplying,

$ (V_{1y} - s \sin \theta )( Q_{0x} - P_{0x} ) - (V_{1x} - s \cos \theta ) (Q_{0y} - P_{0y} )  = 0 $

This is a simple trigonometric equation that can be solved as follows:

Write the above equation in the form

$ A \cos \theta + B \sin \theta = C $

where

$ A = s ( Q_{0y} - P_{0y} ) $

$ B = - s ( Q_{0x} - P_{0x} ) $

$ C = V_{1x} ( Q_{0y} - P_{0y} ) - V_{1y} (Q_{0x} - P_{0x} ) $

Then the solutions for $\theta$ are given by

$ \theta = \alpha \pm \beta $

where

$ \alpha = \text{Atan2}( A, B ) $

$ \beta = \cos^{-1} \left( \dfrac{ C }{ \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}} \right) $

Note that the $\text{Atan2}(x,y)$ function returns the angle $\theta$ that satisfies $\cos \theta = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $ and $\sin \theta = \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $

For each of the two solutions $\theta_1 = \alpha + \beta $ and $\theta_2 = \alpha - \beta $, the collision time can be calculated from

$ t (V_1 - s u) = Q_0 - P_0 $

Therefore,

$ t = \dfrac{ Q_{0x} - P_{0x} } { V_{1x} - s \cos \theta_i } = \dfrac{ Q_{0y} - P_{0y} } { V_{1y} - s \sin \theta_i } $

**Numerical Example:**

Let $P_0 = (10,2), Q_0 = (5, 6), V_1 = (-3, 1), s = 2 $

The two figures below show the two possible solutions computed using the formulas above.  The target's trajectory is shown in red, and the missile's trajectory in blue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it's uncool to thank people on Stack Exchange but thanks. That's a really comprehensive answer with a helpful graphic illustrating the solution. Thank you for taking the time to produce it.

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

I think for computational stability and performance reasons it's best to avoid using (inverse) trigonometric functions. For this reason, we should look for the velocity vector directly, rather than its angle. It would also generalize well to higher dimensions, if ever needed. Here's a somewhat simple solution that only requires a square root and finds $V_m$.

Let $P(t) = O_p + t V_p$ and $M(t) = O_m + t V_m$ be the player and the missile positions in $t$ seconds.

We assume the original positions of the player and the missile $O_p$ and $O_m$ known, as well as the velocity of the play $V_p$ and the absolute velocity of the missile $|V_m|=V$.

We want $P(t) = M(t)$ for some $t > 0$, and we can vary $V_m$ as long as $|V_m| = V$:
$$
\begin{cases}
|V_m| = V, \\
O_p - O_m = t(V_m - V_p), \\
t > 0.
\end{cases}
$$
To solve the system above, we can replace the first equation with $V_m \cdot V_m = V^2$, and then find the square length of left- and right-hand sides in the expression below:
$$
t V_m = t V_p + (O_p - O_m).
$$
Finding their dot products with themselves, we get a quadratic equation on $t$:
$$
t^2 V^2 = t^2 |V_p|^2 + |O_p-O_m|^2 + 2 t V_p \cdot(O_p - O_m),
$$
which we can solve as
$$
t = \frac{B \pm \sqrt{B^2+AC}}{A},
$$
where
$$\begin{align}
A &= V^2 - |V_p|^2, \\
B &= V_p \cdot (O_p - O_m), \\
C &= |O_p-O_m|^2.
\end{align}$$

Then you pick $+$ or $-$ in such way that $t > 0$, if it's possible at all. Note that the case $V = |V_p|$ requires special consideration, as it makes the equation linear, with the only solution
$$
t=\frac{|O_p-O_m|^2}{2 V_p \cdot (O_m - O_p)} = - \frac{C}{2B}
$$

One final remark is that we did not find the angle of $V_m$ explicitly. But we don't really need it!

$$
V_m = V_p + (O_p - O_m) t^{-1}
$$
is the vector velocity for the missile. We can find the angle as e.g. $\theta = \operatorname{atan2}(V_{my}, V_{mx})$, but it would be faster and more computationally stable to just use $V_m$ directly.

Quick proof of concept Python implementation:

```
from random import *
from math import sqrt

def dot(A, B):
    return (A*B.conjugate()).real

def getV(Op, Om, Vp, V):
    A = V**2-dot(Vp, Vp)
    B = dot(Vp, Op-Om)
    C = dot(Op-Om, Op-Om)
    t = -1
    if A == 0:
        t = -C / (2 * B)
    else:
        D = B**2+A*C
        if D < 0:
            return None
        if A > 0:
            t = (B + sqrt(B**2+A*C)) / A
        else:
            t = (B - sqrt(B**2+A*C)) / A
    if t < 0:
        return None
    Vm = Vp + (Op - Om) / t
    assert abs(dot(Vm, Vm) - V**2) < 10**-6
    return Vm

Op = 0
Om = random() + random() * 1j
Vp = random() + random() * 1j
V = 2*random()

getV(Op, Om, Vp, V)
```